# React native console.debug is not working in a new project

Tags: git, react-native, console

[image]

i started a new react-native project, and installed few libraries that my projects required.

everything was works great untill i changed ios run schema from release -> debug.

ever since, console.log commands are not working properly, even after i changed the schema back to debug, now console.log works, but console.debug is not working anymore !

as you can see from gif above, what is the problem with my console.debug ?

it case you was wondering the react-native project that i show above is hosted on git `https://github.com/alzalabany/madina`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are filtering by "Info", select "Verbose" and it will show up (on top bar on dev tools)

Comment: :S spend last 2 days banging my head to wall !! thanks @UXDart